# A std::string gets a totally unexpected value

Tags: c++, string

My class has a member `std::string received;`, initialized at an empty string in its constructor, along with a function `printReceived` that prints the string to `cout`.

In `main()`, an instance of the above class is created, and `printReceived` is called.

Instead of getting an empty string, I get **totally unexpected values** (but always the same):

- If `printReceived` is `std::cout<<"Received ":<<received<<std::endl;`, I get

  `Received: eived:`  as output.
- A string constant present in a function of another class *which is not called*, if this file is linked.

Where could that come from ? It's getting me mad... All variables are correctly initialized. I've never had this problem before, and I've programmed a lot in C++.

Here is a complete minimal example as asked:

**CellularTest.cpp**

```
#include "A.h"

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    A s;

    s.println("AT+CSQ");
    
    return 0;
}
```

**A.cpp**

```
#include "A.h"

A::A()
: received("")
{
}
void A::println(char* s)
{
    received+=s+'\n';
    treatReceived();
}
void A::treatReceived()
{
    std::cout<<"Received: "<<received<<std::endl;
}
```

**A.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A
{
    public:
        A();
        void println(char* s);
    private:
        std::string received;
        void treatReceived();
};
```

**Makefile**

```
CellularTest: CellularTest.o CellularTest.cpp A.o
    g++ CellularTest.o A.o -o CellularTest

CellularTest.o: CellularTest.cpp

A.o: A.cpp A.h

clean:
    rm *.o
    rm CellularTest
```

The output I get is:

```
Received: eived:
```

Comment: Rather than trying to describe your code, why not just post some representative code that exhibits the problem?

Comment: can you show more of your coded?

Comment: Let us see the initialization - even better compilable code that shows the issue.

Comment: That's not even valid syntax, should be something like `std::cout << "Received:" << received << std::endl;`

Comment: @Chris he obviously didn't copy and paste it. Which is the problem actually, he didn't copy and paste _anything_.

Comment: All the more reason for the OP to paste the real code.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that it was a better idea to ask what could cause that kind of behaviour than giving code and asking people to debug it. But I was probably wrong.

Comment: Note that conversion from a string literal (which is of type `const char*`) to a `char*` is deprecated since eons. Your compiler should warn you about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`operator+=` has lower precedence than `operator+`. So in `println`, you're doing this:

```
received+=(s+'\n');
```

Which is like

```
received+=(s+10);
```

Which is incrementing the pointer `s` by 10 bytes and then appending the string pointed to by the resulting `char*` to `received`, and the string literal `Recieved:` is happening to be stored just after the string literal `AT+CSQ`. So memory might look like `AT+CSQ\0Received: \0` and incrementing `AT+CSQ` by 10 is actually the `e` in `Received:`. So there you have it.

Change that to

```
received+=s;
received+='\n';
```

Or alternatively

```
received = received + s + '\n';
```

Comment: Also good would be to change signature to `println(const std::string& s)`.

Comment: So this explains too why string constants from others, non-used, functions were printed too... Thank you!

Comment: @Klaus yep, the compiler often stores literal strings packed one after another in the executable itself.

Comment: @msandiford Or `const char *`. g++ complains about the conversion from string constant to char * in the original code (even without -Wall)

Answer (score 1):

```
void A::println(char* s)
{
    received+=s+'\n';
```

You've clearly never dealt with primitive strings. Firstly- always take as a `const char*` or `std::string` - because it's undefined behaviour to modify the contents. Secondly, your `+` is actually performing *pointer arithmetic*, i.e., `received += &s['\n'];`, *not* concatenation. The host string is clearly not large enough for the value of `\n` which is 13 or so, IIRC, and therefore your program exhibits Undefined Behaviour.

If you want to use strings in C++, and you're not extremely sure of what you're doing, *always* deal in `std::string`, because it's impossible for this sort of thing to happen.